# References Path in VS Package Unit Test in VS 2012 - VSSDK 11.0 paths to VS 2013 - VSSDK 13.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-sdk, assembly-references

I have Windows 8.1 x64, VS 2008, VS 2010, **VS 2012 x86, VS 2013 x86**, Visual Studio SDKs (2010, **2012, 2013**).

I have Visual Studio Extensibility projects: VS Package project, VS Package Integration Tests project an VS Package Unit Tests project.

**Target Framework 4.0** and **VS 2012 (version 11.0)**, not VS 2013 (version 12.0).

VS Package Unit Tests project not compiles for me, about Microsoft.VSSDK.UnitTestLibrary.

In VS Package Unit Tests project, I have this reference

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.VSSDK.UnitTestLibrary" />
```

I view References Properties, Path property value

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\VSSDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Assemblies\v4.0\Microsoft.VSSDK.UnitTestLibrary.dll

Not right, it should be

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   11.0\VSSDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Assemblies\v4.0\Microsoft.VSSDK.UnitTestLibrary.dll

Another references has assembly path  to VS 12.0, not VS 11.0:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop
Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SDK SP1\VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Assemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.dll

Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll


Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.11.0
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VSSDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Assemblies\v4.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.11.0.dll

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Immutable.10.0
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VSSDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Assemblies\v4.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Immutable.10.0.dll

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Immutable.11.0
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VSSDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Assemblies\v4.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Immutable.11.0.dll

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SDK SP1\VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Assemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.dll

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.10.0
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SDK SP1\VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Assemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.10.0.dll

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.11.0
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VSSDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Assemblies\v4.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.11.0.dll

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SDK SP1\VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Assemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0.dll

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.9.0
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SDK SP1\VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Assemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.9.0.dll

Microsoft.VSSDK.TestHostFramework
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VSSDK.TestHostFramework.dll
```

My project is for .NET 4.5, in solution for VS 2012.

Why any references path to VS 2013 (version VSSDK 12.0) ?

It should be path to VSSDK 11.0

Any suggestions?